# Why Isn't the score increasing every round?

Tags: python

I am doing a python project for college and I need to have a scoring system so I can determine a winner of the game.
The code is below:

```
import time
import random


#def player_details(message):

    #name = input(message)
    #return name

#global score
#global count
score = 0
count = 0

def length_card1():


    card = p1card

    length = len(card)

    for i in range(length):
         if card[i].isnumeric():
            global card_number1
            card_number1 = card[I:]
        
            break


def length_card2():

    card = p2card

    length = len(card)

    for i in range(length):
        if card[i].isnumeric():
            global card_number2
            card_number2 = card[I:]
        
            break

# ROUND 1 player 1 and 2 card
def card():

    global p1card
    global p2card
    p1card = (random.choice(new_array))
    new_array.remove(p1card)
    p2card = (random.choice(new_array))

#player_1 = player_details("Player 1: ")
#player_2 = player_details("Player 2: ")


def win(score, count):


    length_card1()
    length_card2()



    #RED DRAW
    if p1card[0] == 'r' and p2card[0] == 'r':
        print("Cards are the same colour...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The card with the highest number wins... Good Luck!!")
        card_numberp1 = card_number1[0: ]
        card_numberp2 = card_number2[0: ]
        if card_numberp1 > card_numberp2:
            print("Player 1 Wins!!")
            score = score +2

        

        else:
            print("Player 2 Wins!!")
            count = count +2



    #BLACK DRAW
    if p1card[0] == 'b' and p2card[0] == 'b':
        print("Cards are the same colour...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The card with the highest number wins... Good Luck!!")
        card_numberp1 = card_number1[0: ]
        card_numberp2 = card_number2[0: ]
        if card_numberp1 > card_numberp2:
            print("Player 1 Wins!!")
            score = score +2

        else:
            print("Player 2 Wins!!")
            count = count +2


    #YELLOW DRAW
    if p1card[0] == 'y' and p2card[0] == 'y':
        print("Cards are the same colour...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The card with the highest number wins... Good Luck!!")
        card_numberp1 = card_number1[0: ]
        card_numberp2 = card_number2[0: ]
        if card_numberp1 > card_numberp2:
            print("Player 1 Wins!!")
            score = score +2

        

        else:
            print("Player 2 Wins!!")
            count = count +2

       

    #RED BEATS BLACK
    if p1card[0] == 'r' and p2card[0] == 'b':
        print("Red Beats Black so...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Player 1 Wins!!") 
        score = score +2


    #BLACK LOSES TO RED
    if p1card[0] == 'b' and p2card[0] == 'r':
        print("Red Beats Black so...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Player 2 Wins!!")
        count = count +2




    #YELLOW BEATS RED
    if p1card[0] == 'y' and p2card[0] == 'r':
        print("Yellow Beats Red so...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Player 1 Wins!!")
        score = score +2

    
    #RED LOSES TO YELLOW
    if p1card[0] == 'r' and p2card[0] == 'y':
        print("Yellow Beats Red so...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Player 2 Wins!!")
        count = count +2

    

    #BLACK BEATS YELLOW
    if p1card[0] == 'b' and p2card[0] == 'y':
        print("Black Beats Yellow so...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Player 1 Wins!!")
        score = score +2

    
    #YELLOW LOSES TO BLACK
    if p1card[0] == 'y' and p2card[0] == 'b':
        print("Black Beats Yellow so...")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Player 2 Wins!!")
        count = count +2

    


    new_array.remove(p2card)

    return score, count
    



#makes deck and shuffles it
colour = ['red', 'yellow', 'black']

array = []

for i in colour:
    for j in range(1,11):
        temp = i + " " + str(j)
        array.append(temp)
new_array = list(array)
random.shuffle(new_array)

#GETS ROUND 1 CARDS AND WINNER
card()
print("Player 1 your first card was", p1card)
time.sleep(1)
print("Player 2 your first card was", p2card)
win(score, count)

nextround = input("Press ENTER to go to the next round: ")


#GETS THE ROUNDS CARDS AND WINNER#
card()
print("Player 1 your next card was", p1card)
time.sleep(1)
print("Player 2 your next card was", p2card)
win(score, count)

nextround = input("Press ENTER to go to the next round: ")

def round():

    #GETS THE ROUNDS CARDS AND WINNER
    card()
    print("Player 1 your next card was", p1card)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Player 2 your next card was", p2card)
    win(score, count)
    nextround = input("Press ENTER to go to the next round: ")


for i in range(12):
    round()


#FINAL ROUND CARDS AND WINNER
card()
print("Player 1 Your Final Card was", p1card)
time.sleep(1)
print("Player 2 Your Final Card was", p2card)
win(score, count)

print(score)
print(count)
```

After Each time the *WIN* subroutine is run the scores for each player should increase by 2 each round the player wins. Instead, the scores stay at 0. Is there a way I can make the scores increase by 2 each round?

Comment: You return `score` from `win` but never actually use that to update the outer `score` variable, so each call just passes in 0, updates it locally within `win`, and then throws away the new value.

Comment: What @Kemp sais: assign the returned variables: `score, count = win(score, count)`

Comment: @RobinSage: no need to loop. You can just call the methods 3 times in 3 different lines as OJJ09 does

Comment: How would i chnge that @Kemp

Answer (score 0):

Remove arguments from win function and declare global score and count in win function

```
def win():
    global score
    global count
```

and then change all calls from `win(score, card)` => to `win()`

I tested your code for few rounds and it was increasing score by 2 per win for a player.